# can't fetching json in flutter

Tags: flutter

It Work When String is used BUT Can't fetch String Object.

it Works :-

```
String? url = "https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search";
        
    var raw = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

it is Not working :-

```
getInfoFromSharedPref() async {
    dogApiLink = await SharedPreferenceHelper().getDogName();
                        }

    var raw = await http.get(Uri.parse('${dogApiLink}'));
```

where dogApiLink is String and having Link But Not working.

Answer (score 0):

bro it's direct .. I just don't understand if the return from the shared preferences that you are taking is a link ???? if it's only dog name then that's your problem.. if it's a legitimate link then

```
{
String uri = "The link";
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), "The headers of the api").then(){
   // The task you wanna perform. 
  }
}
```

Comment: sometimes when you try not to use " then(){} " it cause an error.. so try to use this approach